# Trouble installing package "OpenStreetMap" in RStudio

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install `OpenStreetMap` in RStudio.
I am under `OS 10.11.3`.
My java version is :
`➜  ~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)`

When I install it I have the following message :
`

> install.packages("OpenStreetMap")
>   Installing package into ‘/Users/anhnguyen/Library/R/3.2/library’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  2 2209k    2 49152    0     0  61339      0  0:00:36 --:--:--  0:00:36 61286 29 2209k   29  658k    0     0   367k      0  0:00:06  0:00:01  0:00:05  367k 95 2209k   95 2114k    0     0   757k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  757k100 2209k  100 2209k    0     0   774k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  774k
>   The downloaded binary packages are in /var/folders/qm/gj1n93fd7rg8rgz1ldq19gm80000gn/T//Rtmpuwj9O5/downloaded_packages
>   `

Then when loading the library I have :
`

> library(OpenStreetMap)
>   JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
>   JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
>   JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
>   Error in .jinit() : JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1
>   Error : .onLoad a échoué dans loadNamespace() pour 'OpenStreetMap', détails :
>     appel : fun(libname, pkgname)
>     erreur : Java classes could not be loaded. Most likely because Java is not set up with your R installation.
>   Here are some trouble shooting tips:
>   1. Install Java
>   2. Run 
>       R CMD javareconf
>   in the terminal. If you are using Mac OS X >= 10.7 you may want to try
>       R CMD javareconf JAVA_CPPFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
>   instead.
>   Erreur : le chargement du package ou de l'espace de noms a échoué pour ‘OpenStreetMap’
>   `

I have already installed other packages without problem.
I have read that it might missed `rjava` and has installed it as well without solving my current problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, in spite of having java already installed I did this:

1) I reinstalled java with this link https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US  without removing my already installed java
2) I ran in my terminal `R CMD javareconf` though my MacOS was >= 10.7

I have to say that months ago I did solve this problem and even though today the same error appeared again.